# Vector based colour plot

Tags: r

I have a vector z like this

```
z <- as.numeric(as.factor(c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H")))
```

and for different days a data frame df like this

```
df[[1]]

ID     LON     LAT

A     1        1
B     10        14
C     12        13

df[[2]]

ID     LON     LAT

A     2         3
B     11        18
D     12        13

df[[3]]

ID     LON     LAT

A     13        1
E     10        14
D     12        13
```

where the IDs are the ones in z but can be different for every day.

I have assigned a colour to each element of the vector

```
range01 <- function(x)(x-min(x))/diff(range(x))
rainbow(7)
cRamp <- function(x){
cols <- colorRamp(rainbow(7))(range01(x))
apply(cols, 1, function(xt)rgb(xt[1], xt[2], xt[3], maxColorValue=255))
}
```

I would like to plot, for every day, my df with the colours cRamp(z), but I have so far been unable to link the ID value in every df with the one in z.

Here is my code:

```
for (i in 1:length(mydf)){

  plot(df[[i]]$LON,df[[i]]$LAT, col = cRamp(z))
  map(add=T,col="saddlebrown",interior = FALSE)
  legend("topleft", legend=c(unique(df[[i]]$ID)), col=cRamp(z))
}
```

but the colours for e.g. ID A are not the same for every day!

Many thanks!

Comment: I've voted to close this question as being off-topic. It seems you just want help with the R code - which is more appropriate for Stackoverflow.

Comment: I hesitated to do the same (though it was my first inclination as well) because "**visualizing data**" is listed as on-topic on our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)...Went ahead with flagging it nevertheless.

Comment: Well, there it is! No harm in closing it now eh?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to find the corresponding indices of `df[[j]]$ID` values in `z` .  Here's a simple approach.

```
Rgames> foo<-c('a','b','c','d')
Rgames> bar <- c('b','d','a')
Rgames> indmatch <- match(bar,foo) 
# As Roland pointed out, much better than "sapply(bar,function(j)which(foo==j))"

#b d a 
#2 4 1
```

So if you take that output you can use it as the index into your colors:

`col=cRamp(z)[indmatch]`

Comment: `match(bar, foo)` as I show in the duplicate.